# Строковый тип в switch case

Tags: c++, switch

Можно ли написать конструктор switch case со строковым типом переменных C++ ???

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду: использовать switch со string - то нет.

Comment: До С++17, точно нет.

Comment: и вообще не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под: конструктор switch case - switch не является классом, это оператор, который, если не ошибаюсь, нельзя перегрузить. Если же вы хотите написать свой класс, похожий на switch, то назвать вам его придется по другому, так как это название уже занято. И, если честно, я не представляю себе удобного класса, анологичного switch.

Comment: std::map возьмите, да не мучайтесь.

Comment: Лень if-ы писать? )
Можно попробовать захешировать и потом их сравнивать, если принципиально хочется switch-case.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/166201/ гляньте тут, решение на макро и хэшах, вкратце, хэш строки в case сравнивается с хэшем строки в свиче, обвязка синтаксиса - макросы.